# Optimization problem of find a pair of values (x, y) such that they produce an output z

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, finance

**Problem**

I am trying to create a process that determines the rent and purchase price of a home that gives me a capitalization rate of 0.08 for instance.

**Background**

Normally I calculate the capitalization rate by estimating revenue, operating expenses, net operating income, and other fees associated with buying a home.

The capitalization rate is then:

```py
cap_rate = net_operating_income/purchase_price
net_operating_income = revenue - operating_expenses
revenue = annual_rent - annual_vacancy
operating_expenses = annual_expenses
# annual expenses would be things like maintenance costs, property management fees, property taxes, etc.
```

I normally use a more refined version of the cap rate called the stabilized cap rate which takes into account initial costs for purchasing the home, closing the deal, and possible shortfalls.

```py
stabilized_cap_rate = net_operating_income/(purchase_price + initial_costs + closing_costs + shortfalls)
initial_costs = renovations + contingency + other_initial_costs
closing_costs = legal_fees + financing_fees + other_closing_costs
shortfall = operating_expenses * time_no_one_lives_in_the_property
```

In this process I have an initial rent estimate, purchase price estimate, all my operating costs, and everything i need to calculate the stabilized cap rate. But I am not sure how I can reverse this process such that given a stabilized capitalization rate I can find the rent, purchase price pair that produces that stabilized capitalization rate.

Many (rent, purchase price) combinations will give me a value of 0.08 but I am trying to find a quick way to get this pair and then apply different constraints on it such as maximim purchase price and maximize rent such that stabilized capitalization rate is 0.08 or minimize rent and maximize purchase price such that the stabilized capitalization rate is 0.08.

**Solution attempts**

I have a brute force approach but it takes too long to run. I haven't timed it but maybe an hour. and I tried using the scipy optimize library with the minimize function but did not get good results from any of the optimizers. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or give me some direction on how I should go about doing this?
from scipy.optimize import minimize.

**Update: see my answer below for explanation of solution. No code provided though. Message if you need help or code.

Answer (score 1):

Updating for anyone stuck in a similar situation.

Wanted to give an update for anyone in a similar solution. Found a simpler answer. If you have formulas for everything you likely don't need optimization although it can still be used. Instead you can create a matrix of rent and purchase price values that give you the desired stabilized cap rate and then explore that resultant space for rent, purchase price pairs or even ranges of purchase price to rents that meet your criteria.

You can create a matrix of the rent and purchase price values and evaluate the pairs that give you the cap rate you want. Or you can plot the rent, and purchase price with cap rates to get a plane in an x,y,z coordinate axis. Then use optimization to find the best cap rate with constraints on rent and purchase price to bound it to a local region of the plane.

If anyone is interested to know more just let me know.